# Printing data from listview (userform) to sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a user form that can make recipes and print them to a sheet in my workbook.

I have a listview where all the ingredients and amounts are listed.

When i push a button I want the info from the listview copied to a sheet.

The Userform goes to debug when it reaches "subitems" (line 7 of the code) saying it is an "invalid qualifier"

Below is the bit of code:

```
LastRow2 = Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(Worksheets("Opskrifter").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

lngIndex = 0

Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = TextBox2.Value

loop1:

LastRow2 = LastRow2 + 1

lngIndex = lngIndex + 1

Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = ListView1.ListItems(lngIndex1).SubItems(0).Text

Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(LastRow2, 2).Value = ListView1.ListItems(lngIndex1).SubItems(1).Text

If lngIndex1 < ListView1.ListItems.Count Then GoTo loop1
```

Can anyone help me with what i need to change in the code to make it work as intended?

-Sub questions:

Is `subitem(0)` the correct term for the first column in the listview?

Is `.Text` the right way to select the data in the `listview`?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is you question? And please format your code properly.

Comment: Hi, my question is what i need to change to make my code print from the listview to a datasheet. 
The code has now been formatted

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this expression: `Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = ListView1.ListItems(lngIndex1).SubItems(0).Text` is too long for VBA. Split it this way:

```
Dim li As ListItem
Set li = ListView1.ListItems(lngIndex1)
Worksheets("Opskrifter").Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = li.SubItems(0).Text
```